# Is there any way to describe the type in scala 2 for case classes companion-objects of particular type?

Tags: scala

Is there any way to describe the type in scala for case classes companion-objects of particular type ?

For example I have

```scala
trait SomeTrait

case class Foo() extends SomeTrait
case class Bar() extends SomeTrait
```

And I need to get common type for companion object of Foo and Bar
like `[Foo.type & Bar.type]`

Comment: No, there is no common _(useful)_ supper type for the companions other than `Any` and `Singleton` - You may create another `trait` that the companion objects must extend or maybe a **typeclass** would be better.

Comment: How are you intending to use it?

Comment: I just need to remove this trait-companion, cause this pattern became too complex. Cause I do not want to produce a lot abstractions if in essence, I need only one abstraction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create another trait that the companion objects will extend. If you need to make the companion objects pattern matchable, add `case` in front of them, and make the trait they extend `sealed` for exhaustivity reasons:

```
sealed trait SomeTrait
sealed trait AnotherTrait

case class Foo() extends SomeTrait
case class Bar() extends SomeTrait

case object Foo extends AnotherTrait
case object Bar extends AnotherTrait
```

And for example you can see which object you pattern matched with something like:

```
  def methodName(x: AnotherTrait): String = x match {
    case Foo => "it is Foo singleton"
    case Bar => "it is Bar singleton"
  }

println(methodName(Foo)) // it is Foo singleton
```